# calculation values using SAS

Tags: loops, count, sas

I have one dataset like this:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
5  8  9
9 11 12
```

so I want to make a restriction for the data.

For example:

```
   a(2) - b(1) >=1 and a(2) -c(1) >=1
   a(3) - b(2) >=1 and a(3) -c(2) >=1
```

`a(2)` means the second line for variable `a`,and etc.

How do I write the code for that restriction in SAS?

`a(2) - b(1) >=1 and a(2) -c(1) >=1`

Expected Output:

```
a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Look up the lag function otherwise.

Comment: @Reese I want to write a function like a(2) - b(1) >=1 and a(2) -c(1) >=1 to restrict that dataset,so if a(2) - b(1) >=1 and a(2) -c(1) >=1,the value will retain

Comment: Which value will you retain, the first or second row. SAS doesn't process data the way other languages typically do, unless you go into IML. Posting what you expect the output to look like will help answer your question.

Comment: @Reese I just added the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input a b c;
cards;
1 2 3
4 5 6
5 8 9
9 11 12
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    diffab=a-lag(b);
    diffac=a-lag(c);

    if (diffab<1 or diffac<1) and _n_>2 then delete;
run;
```